# How to save, edit, and create new record in Access Query with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I have a task from school to make a simple program with VB.NET and currently having an issue now. I've connected my MS Access Query (Query, not Table) with my form in VS2015. The program run smoothly, but when I want to update the data, this error message came up

> TableAdapterManager contains no connection information. Set each TableAdapterManager TableAdapter property to a valid TableAdapter instance.

I used this following code to update the database

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.JoblistBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Joblist)
End Sub
```

I need this program to run as late as Thursday.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks before.

Comment: How would you update a query? A query contains no data of its own. ALL data is stored in tables. You can expose that data via a view or a query but the data still lives in a table. You can get the data exposed via a view or query into your application but you cannot push data back into the query because there's nowhere to put data. You still need to push data into the table(s) that the query itself pulls data from. I've never done it with Access but I think that you can use queries like stored procedures, so separate queries can be used for insert, update and delete.

Comment: That make sense to me. So if I replace the datasource from query to the original tables, will it work?

Comment: A query is effectively read-only. If you want to be able to save data, you need to either use a table as the source, in which case the action commands will be generated automatically, or else create the action commands yourself in the DataSet designer.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping mate.

Comment: In Access, data can be edited via query, as long as it's an editable query, which some are not such as aggregate query. I suppose is different with VB.net.